# Use a vector of pairs as an unordered_map

Tags: c++, std, stdvector, stdmap

I initially started out by using an unordered_map to store the frequencies of a certain number appearing and then later using a priority_queue to implement a max heap in order to get the first element which appeared maximum number of times. However unordered_map doesn't preserve the order of insertion and I was thinking to use a vector of pairs for this instead.

I tried to implement this earlier with `unordered_map<int,int>mp` and i could simply count the frequency by doing `mp[element]++` however since vector<int,int> isn't a valid template I need to use `vector<pair<int,int>> vec`. How can I count the frequency of the element in this?
I tried using find with a pair of vector and tried both `if(find(vec.begin().first,vec.end().first,node)==vec.end().first)`
and
`if(find(vec.first.begin(),vec.first.end(),node)==vec.first.end())`. If these don't seem to work how can I find that element and change its freq value?

Comment: What is your actual assignment or exercise? Please copy-paste it (in full and complete, with all requirements and limitations, and as text) into your question. If you ask about that directly instead, we will be able to help you much better.

Comment: An important aspect is whether you need to find the most common element after every insertion/update or just at the very end after counting all entries

Comment: Are your keys contiguous and do they have a limited range?  If so, you could just use `std::vector<int>` and pre-allocate a big enough vector to hold the entire range of your keys (i.e. if counting the frequency of ASCII characters or similar).

Comment: Why do you need to keep the order of insertion?

Answer (score 1):

Using `std::vector` is inefficient. It would be much better to use `std::map`.

Nevertheless if to use a vector and it is unsorted then you need to use standard algorithm `std::find_if`.

Here is a demonstration program that shows how it can be done.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v;

    for (auto key : { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1 })
    {
        auto present = [=]( const auto &p ) { return p.first == key; };

        auto pos = std::find_if( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ), present );

        if (pos == std::end( v ))
        {
            v.emplace_back( key, 1 );
        }
        else
        {
            ++pos->second;
        }
    }

    for ( const auto &p : v )
    {
        std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1: 2
2: 5
3: 4
4: 3
5: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply want to keep track of the insertion order into a `std::unordered_map` in a `std::vector<std::unordered_map<...>::value_type*>`. You may want to write a wrapper type for this.

```
template<class Key, class Value>
class MyMap
{
    using Map = std::unordered_map<Key, Value>;
    using Entry = std::unordered_map<Key, Value>::value_type;
    using ConstEntry = std::add_const_t<Entry>;

    Map m_map;
    std::vector<typename Map::value_type*> m_insertionOrder;
public:
    auto& operator[](Key const& key)
    {
        auto insertResult = m_map.try_emplace(key);
        if (insertResult.second)
        {
            try
            {
                m_insertionOrder.push_back(&*insertResult.first);
            }
            catch (...)
            {
                m_map.erase(key);
                throw;
            }
        }

        return insertResult.first->second;
    }

    template<bool isConst>
    class IteratorImplementation
    {
        std::vector<typename Map::value_type*>::const_iterator m_pos;
    public:
        using value_type = std::conditional_t<isConst, ConstEntry, Entry>;
        using reference = value_type&;
        using difference_type = void;
        using pointer = value_type*;
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

        IteratorImplementation(std::vector<typename Map::value_type*>::const_iterator pos) noexcept
            : m_pos(pos)
        {
        }
        
        bool operator==(IteratorImplementation const& other) const noexcept
        {
            return m_pos == other.m_pos;
        }
        
        bool operator!=(IteratorImplementation const& other) const noexcept
        {
            return m_pos != other.m_pos;
        }

        reference operator*() const
        {
            return **m_pos;
        }

        pointer operator->() const
        {
            return *m_pos;
        }

        IteratorImplementation& operator++()
        {
            ++m_pos;
            return *this;
        }

        IteratorImplementation operator++(int)
        {
            IteratorImplementation result = *this;
            ++(*this);
            return result;
        }
    };

    auto begin() const noexcept
    {
        return IteratorImplementation<true>(m_insertionOrder.begin());
    }

    auto end() const noexcept
    {
        return IteratorImplementation<true>(m_insertionOrder.end());
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 25; ++i)
    {
        values.push_back(i);
    }

    for (int i = 25; i >= 0; i -= 2)
    {
        values.push_back(i);
    }

    MyMap<int, int> map;

    for (auto e : values)
    {
        ++map[e];
    }

    for (auto [key, value] : map)
    {
        std::cout << key << " -> " << value << '\n';
    }

    auto maxElement = std::max_element(map.begin(), map.end(), [](std::pair<const int, int> const& v1, std::pair<const int, int> const& v2)
        {
            return v1.second < v2.second;
        });

    std::cout << "max: " << maxElement->first << '\n';

}
```